# Searching PDF using PDFKIT in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I am extremely new to swift so bear with me. I am trying to figure out how to search the PDF document for a particular string. I am assuming I need to use the findString function. I just do not know exactly how the parameters should be implemented. I am using [Apple Docs.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit/pdfdocument/1436060-findstring) and couldn't see a description of this.

Thanks!=]

```
  private func loadPDF(){
            guard
                let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: pdfTitle, withExtension: "pdf"),
                let document = PDFDocument(url:url)
                else {fatalError()}
                pdfView.document = document

        }

func findString(_ string: String, 
    withOptions options: NSString.CompareOptions = []) -> [PDFSelection]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a list of matches you do something like this:

```
let matches = document.findString("foo", withOptions: .caseInsensitive)
```

Comment: Cannot invoke 'go' with an argument list of type '(to: String)' is the error I keep getting, thoughts?

Comment: @mrwadepro I don't see `go` in any of the code you've shown, so I think that is an unrelated problem.

Comment: I copied the same line of code and pasted it and it worked